# How to use a Tag-like Edit Text in Android

Tags: java, android, material-design

Is there any way to create a EditText similar to the very same Tag system available here, in StackOverflow, when asking a question?

Or any library for the same purpose?

I want to do something similar in my app:

I already have an EditText field and, where the user inputs a topic, for instance, 'java', and then, when the user inputs ';', I want to mark that word in a color, blue or gray for example, to highlight that it is a tag. Then, the user can input another tag, i.e 'android', or can delete the previous tag like it was a text.

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic here.  If you have a specific question about doing it yourself, ask.  But its too broad in and of itself.

Comment: I don't care between doing it by myself or with a library. I was just asking for any possibility.

Comment: I'm not sure why this kind of questions are not allowed, for what I concern is valid. There will be plenty of times in a developer carrier when you want to do something but don't know the name, even Google is not a way to figure it out because without knowing the keywords to search the results will be wasteful. What you are looking is a Material Design pattern called "chips" https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html another user have provided with a library and some example, if you ask me he should get the correct answer. Good Luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're describing [chips](https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html).

You can take a look at the [MaterialChipsInput](https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput) library. Instead of using an `EditText` you'll use `ChipInput`:

```
<com.pchmn.materialchips.ChipsInput
        android:id="@+id/tag_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hint="Add a tag" />
```

Comment: I forgot this was an option. Thank you very much! :D